# PDO - COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm using Symfony2 (2.3) and trying to write session data into db. 
I use the PDOSessionHandler with a MSSQL 2012 db (sqlsrv as driver)
Unfortunately I always get a PDO Error:

```
'SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error'
```

The statement which is prepared by the PDOSessionHandler  class is as follows:

```
MERGE INTO session WITH (HOLDLOCK) USING (SELECT 1 AS dummy) AS src ON (session_id = :id) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (session_id, session_value, session_time) VALUES (:id, :data, :time) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET session_value = :data, session_time = :time;
```

From my point of view this seems to be incorrect, because the same parameters are used more than once. This is accoring to pdo manual not allowed: (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to
>   pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You
>   cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in
>   a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Is this a symfony2 bug or are I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 workaround:

1. You either name them differently `:id2`, `:data2`, `:time2`
2. You enable `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`:

   ```
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
   ```